# How to have nested ajax call back function work sequentially in loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, nested-loops

I have been stuck with this problem for a few days now. 
The program needs to extract information from 2 different xml file through a succession of 3 ajax calls.  The first ajax call get the data from an xml file and depending on specific condition another nested ajax call is used to extract information from another file.  Then the third callback function will extract more info from the first xml file through another nested ajax call.
My problem is that when the first call back function is fired and I parse through the file with an each() function, it goes first through the end of the loop before firing the second ajax and its related call back function, etc.... The different ajax calls and functions are nested correctly I think, but it does not process in succession as it shown in my console log.
I hope I am being clear enough here.
Thank you for your help and advices!!!
Here is the code:

// Ajax call to get the xml produced file

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'orders1.xml',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
                                 console.log("Call successful ! Parsing XML...");

                                 parseorders(xml);

                                     },
                                 error: function() {
                                        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
                                    }
                                     }); 



    function parseorders(xml) {

        $('Orders_id', xml).each(function(i){
            var ordersnum = $(this).attr("Orders_number");
            var customer_number = $(this).find("customers_id").text();
            var datemade = $(this).find('date_made').text();
            var delivery = $(this).find('delivery').text();
            var pickup = $(this).find('pickup').text();

            console.log(i);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "business.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                console.log("Call successful ! Parsing XML...");
                parsebusiness(xml);

                                     }
                    });      



            function parsebusiness(xml) {

                $("businessname", xml).each(function(j) {    

                    var cust = $(this).find('customers_id').text();
                    if (cust === customer_number) {
                    console.log(j);
                    businessnam = $(this).attr('name');
                    lastname = $(this).find('lastname').text();
                    address = $(this).find('address').text();
                    city = $(this).find('city').text();
                    zip = $(this).find('zip').text();
                    phone = $(this).find('phone').text();


                    $('<div></div>').attr('id','reportm' + i).appendTo('#report');
                    $('#reportm' + i ).html( "<br /> <br /> Business: " + businessnam + " <br /> Contact person: " + lastname + "<br /> Address: " + address + "<br /> City: " + city + " <br /> Zip:  " + zip + "<br /> Phone: " + phone + "<br /> Deliver: " + delivery + "<br /> Pick-up: " + pickup + "<br />  Date: " + datemade +"<br /> <br /> <table border='1'> <tbody> <tr> <th> Quantity </th> <th> Item </th> <th> Tax </th> <th> Total </th> </tr>  ");





                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'orders1.xml',
                        type: 'GET',
                        datatype: 'xml',
                        success: function(xml) {
                               console.log("Call successful ! Parsing XML...");

                                 parseorders1(xml);
                                              }
                        }); 

                    function parseorders1(xml) {

                        $('transactions', xml).each(function(m){

                            var orde = $(this).find("Orders_id").text();
                            console.log(orde);
                            if (orde == ordersnum) {
                            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                            var quantity = $(this).find('quantity').text();
                            var tax = $(this).find('tax').text();
                            var total = $(this).find('total').text();

                            $('<div></div>').attr('id','reportd' + m + i).appendTo('#reportm' + i );  
                            $('#reportd' + m + i ).html("<tr> <td> " + name + "</td> <td> " + quantity + "</td> <td> " + tax + "</td> <td> " + total + " </td> </tr> ");
                                                      }
                                                      });

                                              }


            $('<div></div>').attr('id','reporte').appendTo('#reportd'+ m + i );    
            $('#reporte').html("</table> <br /> <br />");    



                                          }           

      });

}






});

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loop is working.  I had a wrong variable name for one of the xml pointer.

It is pretty much working now, only minor problem with the table formatting.